# How to check if a commit removes a file without using git-rm?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

Basically, I want to write a pre-commit hook to check if the about-to-be-committed changes (re)move a file without using `git rm` / `git mv`.

I don't know how to approach this.

Comment: What do you mean by "without using `git rm`/`git mv` - do you mean that you do not want to use either of these in the pre-commit hook?

Comment: I want to check if a file was removed with `rm` or moved with `mv` - so it was _not_ removed using `git rm` or moved using `git mv`. Moving with `mv` causes one to become author of the complete file, which is clumsy when running `git blame` for example.

Comment: Is the question about how to write a git pre-commit hook, or is it about programmatically checking the "about-to-be-committed" changes? Also, what do you intend to do once you find such a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git commit --dry-run` and inspect the output.

Comment: In a pre-commit hook ? Looks like the bash equivalent of a Stack Overflow to me...